# Get user object model that is being changed Django Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

How do you retrieve the model of the user that is currently being changed using the Django admin?

For example you have the change url:

https://www.example.com/admin/users/2/change

I need the user model with the id 2, not the currently logged in user that is found by performing

```
self.request.user
```

EDIT
Note that this is for use on a custom password change view I have implemented using the PasswordChangeView:

```
class PinChangeView(PasswordContextMixin, FormView):
    form_class = SetPinForm
    model = AuthUser
    template_name = 'pin_change_form.html'
    title = _('PIN change')


    @method_decorator(sensitive_post_parameters())
    @method_decorator(csrf_protect)
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)


    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        data = {
            'opts': self.model._meta,
            'original': self.request.user,
            'form': self.get_form(self.get_form_class()),
        }
        return data


    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('admin:users_authuser_change', kwargs={'object_id': self.request.user.id})


    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        messages.add_message(self.request, messages.SUCCESS, _('PIN number updated'))
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

When I use the 'pin change' it gives the details of the currently signed in user, not that of the user being changed.

**Update**

Traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/users/authuser/2/pin_number/

Django Version: 2.2.9
Python Version: 3.8.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'users',
 'hotel',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount']
Installed Middleware:
('whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')



Traceback:

File "/Users/leonhughes/Documents/virtualenvs/django/hlms/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/leonhughes/Documents/virtualenvs/django/hlms/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/leonhughes/Documents/virtualenvs/django/hlms/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/leonhughes/Documents/virtualenvs/django/hlms/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/leonhughes/Documents/virtualenvs/django/hlms/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/leonhughes/Documents/virtualenvs/django/hlms/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py" in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
  76.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/leonhughes/Documents/virtualenvs/django/hlms/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/leonhughes/Documents/virtualenvs/django/hlms/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/leonhughes/Documents/virtualenvs/django/hlms/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/leonhughes/Documents/virtualenvs/django/hlms/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/leonhughes/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/python/django/hlms/users/views.py" in dispatch
  28.         return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/leonhughes/Documents/virtualenvs/django/hlms/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  97.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/leonhughes/Documents/virtualenvs/django/hlms/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in get
  133.         return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())

File "/Users/leonhughes/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/python/django/hlms/users/views.py" in get_context_data
  37.         data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

File "/Users/leonhughes/Documents/virtualenvs/django/hlms/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py" in get_context_data
  198.         context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

File "/Users/leonhughes/Documents/virtualenvs/django/hlms/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/detail.py" in get_context_data
  94.         if self.object:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /admin/users/authuser/2/pin_number/
Exception Value: 'PinChangeView' object has no attribute 'object'
```

Current View Code - have only got kwargs using get_object() at the moment

```
class PinChangeView(PasswordContextMixin, SingleObjectMixin, FormView):
    form_class = SetPinForm
    model = AuthUser
    template_name = 'pin_change_form.html'
    title = _('PIN change')
    pk_url_kwarg = 'object_id'

    @method_decorator(sensitive_post_parameters())
    @method_decorator(csrf_protect)
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.get_object()
        print(kwargs['user'])
        return kwargs

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        data = {
            'opts': self.model._meta,
            'original': self.request.user,
            'form': self.get_form(self.get_form_class()),
        }
        return data

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('admin:users_authuser_change', kwargs={'object_id': self.request.user.id})

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        messages.add_message(self.request, messages.SUCCESS, _('PIN number updated'))
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

**Update 2**

Making changes from the response below I get the error:

```
AttributeError at /admin/users/authuser/2/pin_number/
Generic detail view PinChangeView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.
```

but the path url is:

```
path('<pk>/pin_number/', PinChangeView.as_view(), name='pin_change'),
```

*Current PinChangeView code*

```
class PinChangeView(PasswordContextMixin, SingleObjectMixin, FormView):
    form_class = SetPinForm
    model = AuthUser
    template_name = 'pin_change_form.html'
    title = _('PIN change')
    pk_url_kwarg = 'object_id'
    object = None

    @method_decorator(sensitive_post_parameters())
    @method_decorator(csrf_protect)
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.get_object()
        return kwargs

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        data = {
            'opts': self.model._meta,
            'original': self.request.user,
            'form': self.get_form(self.get_form_class()),
        }
        return data

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('admin:users_authuser_change', kwargs={'object_id': self.request.user.id})

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        messages.add_message(self.request, messages.SUCCESS, _('PIN number updated'))
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Where do you need that? Please show if you have attempted anything yet.

Comment: @NafeesAnwar added code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `SingleObjectMixin` in your view and use `get_object()` method to get `User` object.

```
from django.views.generic.detail import SingleObjectMixin


class PinChangeView(
    SingleObjectMixin,
    ...
):
    model = AuthUser
    pk_url_kwarg = 'object_id'  # because your url param is `object_id`
    object = None


    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.get_object()
        return kwargs
```

Comment: I have implemented your response and am now receiving an error 'PinChangeView' object has no attribute 'object'

Comment: Can you post full traceback?

Comment: You can define `object = None` by default. See the updated answer.

Comment: great - that fixed that issue but another arose - could you check update 2?

Comment: As you have defined `pk` in url, you should remove `pk_url_kwarg = 'object_id'`.